# MatTableDataSource isn't updating with method _updateChangeSubscription()

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a MatTableDataSource with some data. When i do an 'update', i use a method named '_updateChangeSubscription()' to update the table and that's works. I'd like to know, how to update the table when i do a 'POST' or 'DELETE'. I've tried the same method above but with no success

This method updates my table because i am using _updateChangeSubscription()

```
public updateWorkspace() {
        this.workspace['id'] = this.workspace._id;
        this.workspace.createdBy = null;
        this.workspace.createdAt = null;
        this.workspace.updatedBy = this.user;
        this.workspace.updatedAt = new Date();
        this.workspace.language = this.workspaceForm.value.language;
        this.workspace.description = this.workspaceForm.value.description;
        this.workspace.name = this.workspaceForm.value.name;
        this.workspacesService.updateWorkspace(this.workspace).subscribe((response) => {
            alert("SUCESSO")
            this.workspaces._updateChangeSubscription()
            this.workspaceForm.reset(); // fica vermelho os campos
            this.workspace = null;
        }, (error) => {
            alert("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar atualizar o Assunto")
        });
    }
```

this method doesn't works the method _updateChangeSubscription()

```
public updateWorkspace() {
        this.workspace['id'] = this.workspace._id;
        this.workspace.createdBy = null;
        this.workspace.createdAt = null;
        this.workspace.updatedBy = this.user;
        this.workspace.updatedAt = new Date();
        this.workspace.language = this.workspaceForm.value.language;
        this.workspace.description = this.workspaceForm.value.description;
        this.workspace.name = this.workspaceForm.value.name;
        this.workspacesService.updateWorkspace(this.workspace).subscribe((response) => {
            alert("SUCESSO")
            this.workspaces._updateChangeSubscription()
            this.workspaceForm.reset(); // fica vermelho os campos
            this.workspace = null;
        }, (error) => {
            alert("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar atualizar o Assunto")
        });
    }
```

I'd like all my method can update table independent if it's post or delete....